# How to get First Visible child item of android scrollview on scrollChange event

Tags: android, scrollview

I want to get First visible child view from android scrollview, on each scroll change event.
Like, when we scroll down, we get all the upcoming view id or reference that's just being  visible on screen. How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it on my own.. Here is my code:

Here, we need to create our custom callback listener. Inside its onScrollChanged(), We get `int t`  which is scroll's Y position. Extra, we need child Row height and then just divide that `t` by `rowHeight`. Done. We can use `getChildAt()` further.

```
scrollView.setOnScrollViewListener(new OnScrollViewListener() {

    @Override
        public void onScrollChanged(ScrollViewEx v, int l, int t, int oldl,int oldt) {

            int rowHeight = rowView.getHeight();

            int firstPos = t / rowHeight;

            scrollMainChildLL = (LinearLayout) v.getChildAt(0);

            gotTxtLL = (LinearLayout) scrollMainChildLL.getChildAt(firstPos);
    }
 }
```

Comment: what is rowView here , that is not clear , is it an Object of any specific view.

Comment: @Palak what is rowView here?