# How to get First Visible child item of android Horizontal scrollview on scrollChange event

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I need to find the first visible child item of android Horizontal scrollview on scrollChange event. I have followed this link [How to get First Visible child item of android scrollview on scrollChange event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24550862/how-to-get-first-visible-child-item-of-android-scrollview-on-scrollchange-event/24585563)
but couldn't find what rowView is.

```
    horizontalScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {
        int scrollPos = horizontalScrollView1.getScrollX();
        Log.e("scroll x:", scrollPos + "");           
    }
});
```

layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">
        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layLandmarks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <View
                android:id="@+id/viewWhite"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@color/white" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>   
</RelativeLayout>
```

Class file:

```
    ImageView iv;
RelativeLayout layLandmarks = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layLandmarks);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(2000, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layLandmarks.setLayoutParams(lp1);
JSONObject landmarks = jsonObject1.getString("landmarks");
JSONArray jsonArray1 = new JSONArray(landmarks);
for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray1.length(); j++) {
JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(0);

landmarkId = jsonObject2.getString("id");
landmarkName = jsonObject2.getString("title");
landmarkDesc = jsonObject2.getString("description");
latitude = jsonObject2.getDouble("latitude");
longitude = jsonObject2.getDouble("longitude");
video_time = jsonObject2.getString("video_time_in_sec");
//   Log.e("video_time_in_sec", video_time);
landmarkIcon = jsonObject2.getString("image");
iv = new ImageView(VideoPreviewWithRecycler.this);
iv.setId(i);
Picasso
        .with(VideoPreviewWithRecycler.this)
        .load(landmarkIcon)
        .resize(40, 45)
        .into(iv);
params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(40, 45);

params.topMargin = 0;

params.leftMargin = Integer.parseInt(video_time);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 0);

layLandmarks.addView(iv, params);
}
```

Update:

```
 horizontalScrollView1.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScrollChange(View v, final int scrollX, int scrollY, final int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {

                            horizontalScrollView1.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onGlobalLayout() {

                                   int firstVisibleItemIndex= getFirstVisibleItem1(horizontalScrollView1);
                                   Log.e("firstVisibleItemIndex >>",firstVisibleItemIndex+"");
                                }

                            });
                        }
                    });


 private int getFirstVisibleItem1(HorizontalScrollView scrollView) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) scrollView.getChildAt(0); // cast to ViewGroup here because I think we only need to getFirstVisibleItem if ScrollView have multiple items
        for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
            if (view.getX() + view.getWidth() >= scrollView.getScrollX()) {
                return i; // if you want to receive the position, return  i here
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I'd imagine it's a custom class, that packs data sent to it into a fixed height layouts and displays them in a linear layout or smth.

Comment: @IcedLance I'm not using custom class. But the height of the layouts are fixed. I'm using a relative layout.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed at first, that `rowView` at the link you gave is some inherited class with static height function, but on second look it's probably not. What it probably is, is an instance of one row inside a LinearLayout contained inside a ScrollView. It appears they all have a fixed height in that example.

Comment: @Manikandan why don't you Use `Recyclerview`

Answer (score 0):

I think it may help

```
private View getFirstVisibleItem(HorizontalScrollView scrollView) {
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) scrollView.getChildAt(0); // cast to ViewGroup here because I think we only need to getFirstVisibleItem if ScrollView have multiple items
    for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        if (view.getX() + view.getWidth() >= scrollView.getScrollX()) {
            return view; // if you want to receive the position, return turn i here
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The idea is check each `view x position` and `scroll x value`

Comment: I tried you code, and I return i value, But it always return 0.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented some basic scrolling animation in my app. I used this piece of code and it is working perfectly fine.

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, 
LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);




 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            switch (newState) {
                case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
                case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING:
                case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING:
            currentItemPosition=linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

            }
        }
```

my requirement was to find the position during settling of scroll ,you can try the same during SCROLL_STATE_IDLE

Answer (score 0):

There are few methods but I prefer only one.

All Views have "boolean View.getGlobalVisibleRect(..)" ( https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getGlobalVisibleRect(android.graphics.Rect) ) method that returns FALSE if the View is completly hidden by its parent.

So all HorizontalScrollView's child has that HScrollView as its parent and if that method returns FALSE it means that View is not visible. The first child returning TRUE is the first visible child inside that HScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Linearlayout` Instead of `RelaytiveLayout` as a child of `HorizontalScrollView`. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layLandmarks"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="16dp" />

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Note: You can also use custom layout to inflate in views in `LinearLayout` for more performance in case of nested Layouts. (I used a `TextView` not Custom Layout here)**

In your activity use something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView = findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView);
    TextView iv;
    final LinearLayout layLandmarks = findViewById(R.id.layLandmarks);
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        iv = new TextView(this);
        iv.setId(j);
        iv.setText("TEXT " + j);
        iv.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
        layLandmarks.addView(iv);
    }

    horizontalScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
            int firstVisibleItemIndex = getFirstVisibleItem(layLandmarks, horizontalScrollView);
            Log.e("ItemIndex >>", firstVisibleItemIndex + "");
        }
    });
}
```

Now Use the code below. It modified version of *@Phan Van Linh* Answer.

```
private int getFirstVisibleItem(LinearLayout linearLayout, HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView) {
    for (int i = 0; i < linearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View view = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
        if (view.getX() + view.getWidth() >= horizontalScrollView.getScrollX()) {
            return i; // if you want to receive the position, return  i here
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I Hope this will solve your problem. :)